# How to access nested elements of JSON and convert it to CSV

Tags: json

Following is the JSON I need to access.

```
{
    "Timestamp": "2014-05-28 03:31:59",
    "Version": 1,
    "ACK": "success",
    "Errors": {
        "ErrorCode": "433",
        "ShortMessage": "success",
        "LongMessage": "Successfully get all cate information",

    },
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "cate_name": {
                "1": "Women",
                "5": "Женщинам",
                "9": "Femme",
                "10": "Ženy",
                "11": "Kvinder",
                "12": "Women"
            },
            "cate_id": {
                "6": {
                    "cate_name": {
                        "1": "Dresses",
                        "5": "Платья",
                        "9": "Robes",
                        "10": "Šaty",
                        "11": "Kjoler",
                        "12": "Dresses"
                    }
                },
                "14": {
                    "cate_name": {
                        "1": "Vests\/Tank Tops",
                        "5": "Жилеты \/ топы",
                        "9": "Gilets",
                        "10": "Vesty\/Tank topy",
                        "11": "Veste\/Tank Tops",
                        "12": "Vests\/Tank Tops"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "cate_name": {
                "1": "Bags",
                "5": "Сумки",
                "9": "Sacs",
                "10": "Tašky",
                "11": "Tasker",
                "12": "Bags"
            },
            "cate_id": {
                "37": {
                    "cate_name": {
                        "1": "Messenger Bags",
                        "5": "Модные сумки",
                        "9": "Petit Sacs",
                        "10": "Messenger tašky",
                        "11": "Messenger poser",
                        "12": "Messenger Bags"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? what are you programming with?

Comment: First of all I need to retrieve elements from JSON in Java. tried using JsonGen but didnt work. .

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
 JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(line).getAsJsonObject();
 Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> productsJson = jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
 List<ProductData1> allProductData = new ArrayList<ProductData1>();
 ProductData1 product = new ProductData1();
 for(Entry<String, JsonElement> oneProductJson : productsJson){
 product.setCategory_id(oneProductJson.getKey());
 
 System.out.println(oneProductJson.getKey()+'\n');
I am only able to retrieve the keys but cant penetrate to get inside. help would be much appreciated